# CSS auto-increment block width

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to learn some basic CSS/HTML by making myself a static web page. At the bottom of the page I want to show a few 32x32 image icons of websites I go to.

I want to display them inline and put them in the center of the page. Right now I have 3 icons so I created a block of width 96 (= 32x3) and simply center the container block.

However I think there's a good chance that I'll need to add more icons to the list, which means every time a new icon is added, I need to recalculate the width of the container block. **I'm wondering if there is a rule in CSS that would save me from doing that?**

For example I could simply do `text-align: center` for text field regardless of how many words I put in there. Is there something similar for image blocks?

Thanks so much!

**UPDATE**

As in cbp's answer, `text-align` actually also works for img tags. Thanks for pointing that out!

However (sorry for not having made it clear before), I didn't really use the `<img>` but rather `<a>` with CSS setting their background images. So I guess two follow-up questions:

1) Does `text-align: center` still apply here?
2) Is it preferable to use `<a>` (with CSS background-image) over raw HTML `<img>`? Any advantage to use either?

Thanks again!

Comment: Unless your image actually is a background image, strive towards using img tags. Why? Because img tags are for images, and background-image is for background images - that's why. That said, there are occasionally certain tricky cases where you might have to use a background-image instead of an img tag.

Answer (score 2):

By default *text-align: center* will have the same effect on images as it does on text, as img tags have *display: inline* by default.

So you can make the element that contains your imgs have *width: 100%*, then give it *text-align: center*.

Answer (score 1):

Give `Display:inline-block` to your icon `<a>` Tag. Write like this:

```
    .icon{
     width:30px;
     height:30px;
     display:inline-block;
     *display:inline;/*For IE7*/
     *zoom:1;/*For IE7*/
    }
.parent{text-align:center;}
```

Check this http://jsbin.com/epusop/edit#html,live

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` is a bit of a misnomer, as it doesn't act on *just* text. So, yes, you could just use `text-align:center` on the containing element for your images.

Sitepoint reference: [text-align](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-align)

Answer (score 0):

you can use padding and margins in % from there parent elements.